# Accumulate output from PID controller

Tags: pid-controller

I have come across a [handful](https://www.hackster.io/tolgadurudogan/tricks-for-controlling-dc-motors-3a05a5) of [examples](https://github.com/1988kramer/motor_control/blob/master/SpeedControl.cpp#L99) of [PID controllers](https://github.com/RaiseYourArm/MicroMouse_RYA2013/blob/master/PID.c#L164) where the process input is the *accumulated* PID output, i.e. the controller loop is `u += pid(...)` rather than `u = pid(...)` where `u` is the process input.

For the sake of example, say we are using PID to control the speed of a motor via PWM,

```
class PID:
    def __init__(self, kp, ki, kd):
        self.kp = kp
        self.ki = ki
        self.kd = kd

    ...

    def pid(self, set_point, process_variable):
        now = time()
        dt = now - self.last_time

        error = set_point - process_variable
        p = self.kp * error
        i = self.ki * error * dt + self.i_sum
        d = self.kd * (error - self.last_error) / dt
        output = p + i + d

        self.i_sum = i
        self.last_error = error
        self.last_time = now

        return output
```

My understanding of PID is that we should use the controller as

```
pid = PID(kp, ki, kd)
...
motor_pwm = pid.pid(target_speed, measured_speed)
```

But I often see it implemented as

```
pid = PID(kp, ki, kd)
...
motor_pwm += pid.pid(target_speed, measured_speed)
```

Now, for `ki = kd = 0`, the latter makes some intuitive sense to me; in fact, I think it actually gives you a kind of PI controller with `ki = kp`, and `dt = 1` enforced. Once you introduce `ki != 0` or `kd != 0`, however, I can't square this with any of the textbook explanations of PID I have read.

Is this 'accumulated' `u += pid(...)` controller simply an incorrect implementation of PID?

Comment: Can you please show the code or what variable `u` denotes.

Comment: A PI controller is a PID controller with Kd = 0.

Comment: @Long Pham `u` is the process input. The code examples I am referring to are linked in the question.

Comment: Remember, you are asking a bunch of random people on the Internet for help and it's your duty to present the question for them.

Comment: Fair. Question updated.

Comment: If your PID logic can produce infeasible outputs, like calls 150% or -50% PWM duty cycles, its model of reality is wrong and it has lost control.    
 It is simply incorrect.   https://controlguru.com/integral-reset-windup-jacketing-logic-and-the-velocity-pi-form/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily an incorrect implementation, if the feedback signal that your PID loop is tracking and controlling is the first derivative of the control output you need to emit.  The continual accumulation of the PID output is equivalent to integration.

Comment: Typical example: The output of the control loop is a voltage, which a motor turns into speed. Integrated speed is distance.